# SQL Query - LEFT(),20

Tags: sql, active-directory

I have spent a while trying to get a query together to create AD usernames based on 2 column values.

As you may be aware - the limit for these usernames is 20 chars.

The query works for 99% of my current and past data - however, there are still a few names - even after being cut down that equal more than 20 chars. How can my query incorporate the left(), 20 to finally limit the overall result set to be 20 chars or less?

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT          CASE 
                    WHEN LEN(replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName + Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')) > 20
                        THEN
                            CASE
                                WHEN PreName LIKE '%-%' THEN LEFT(replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX('-', (PreName)) - 1) 
                                WHEN PreName LIKE '% %' THEN LEFT(replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX(' ', (PreName)) - 1)
                                ELSE replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')
                            END                             
                                + 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN Surname LIKE '%-%' THEN RIGHT(replace(replace(replace(replace(Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Surname)) - 1) 
                                WHEN Surname LIKE '% %' THEN RIGHT(replace(replace(replace(replace(Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Surname)) - 1)
                                ELSE replace(replace(replace(replace(Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')
                            END 
                    ELSE replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName + Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')
                END AS 'User Name'
FROM            Students
```

Feel free to simplify if i have made any newbie mistakes :)

Comment: include your sample data and expected output for better solution

Comment: Is there a reason it's not as simple as putting the whole CASE statement inside a LEFT() function as the first parameter?

Comment: I have tried that, but when i add the LEFT function it errors on the AS 'User Name'. Could only mean i am starting/ending the function in the wrong place? Where exactly would you add the 'LEFT(' and '),20'. Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to wrap the `CASE` statement in a `LEFT` call, e.g.

```
SELECT          LEFT(CASE ... END, 20) AS 'User Name'
FROM            Students
```

Full code:

```
SELECT          LEFT(CASE 
                WHEN LEN(replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName + Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')) > 20
                    THEN
                        CASE
                            WHEN PreName LIKE '%-%' THEN LEFT(replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX('-', (PreName)) - 1) 
                            WHEN PreName LIKE '% %' THEN LEFT(replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX(' ', (PreName)) - 1)
                            ELSE replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')
                        END                             
                            + 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN Surname LIKE '%-%' THEN RIGHT(replace(replace(replace(replace(Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Surname)) - 1) 
                            WHEN Surname LIKE '% %' THEN RIGHT(replace(replace(replace(replace(Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', ''), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Surname)) - 1)
                            ELSE replace(replace(replace(replace(Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')
                        END 
                ELSE replace(replace(replace(replace(PreName + Surname, ',', ''), ' ', ''), '''', ''), '-', '')
            END, 20) AS 'User Name'
FROM            Students
```

Comment: Thank you! I made a silly mistake and ended the function slightly wrong... Annoying when something so simple.